# how to measure running time of specific function in C++ {very accurate}

Tags: c++, clock

I 'm try to measuring execution of my code in C++.
but that is not very accurate.
Here is my code:

```
std::clock_t start2;
start2 = std::clock();
myFunction();
printf("time of execution: %d ms\r\n",std::clock()-start2);
```

but is not accurate Enough
time of execution is lower then 10 ms but the result is 10 ms or 0 ms and that is not stable.

So i looking for more accurate solution.
any suggestion?

Comment: depends, does your processor hardware provide a high precision timer?

Comment: Try the functions provided by  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono

Comment: My Cpu is intel core I7 2670QM. (asus N43 SM)

Comment: Run the function multiple times and then calculate the average?

Comment: Right. Run the function a few times *before* starting timing (caching warmup), then as many as you think is necessary. Unless the function does something *very* substantial (e.g., heavy calculations; disk access), I usally use around 10,000 iterations. Be careful to take caching into account (either you *never* or *always* want it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock) from the standard [`<chrono>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono) header : it is supposed to represent the most accurate clock available to the implementation.

**Example:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock Clock;
    auto t1 = Clock::now();
    MyFunction();
    auto t2 = Clock::now();
    std::cout <<std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t2 - t1).count() << '\n';
}
```

**Notes:**

- When timing a function, consider runtime the clock N times, to compute a running average, it is much more accurate since you smooth extreme points.
- If you can't use c++11, [`boost::chrono`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/chrono.html) is a very good (and extremely close) alternative.

Comment: and what if `MyFunction()` is preempted during execution ?

Comment: A very recent version of compiler is required, as this is only in C++11. If you don't use such capable compiler, you're struck with OS's specific solution (gettimeofday/clock_gettime on Posix, and QueryPerfCounter/GetSystemTime on Win32)

Comment: @PiotrS. then you measure this as well, I don't think its part of the question.

Comment: @xryl669 "very recent" is subjective. consider the boost chrono header if you cant use c++11

Comment: @PiotrS. : It's part of the measurement, as expected. If you need something deterministic, use a realtime OS, with right priority. Else, the timing should include preemption, since the function might/will be preempted in the real life of the application.

Comment: @quantdev: I think it does matter, the time should be measured based on the processor's ticks program was given, rather than "time points"

Comment: @quantdev: Right, to be more accurate, stl::chrono appeared in Visual Studio 2012. Boost chrono uses OS's primitive, so you don't need to deal with this, althrough it's interesting to know what's underneath.

Comment: @PiotrS.: Tick is not a unit of measurement. You can be preempted numerous time in a single tick. Better to live with it, and accept that a function almost never runs alone, so its "system's" time is part of the elasped time, even if it's not a fixed value.

Comment: visual C++ 2010 : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'chrono': No such file or directory

Comment: @user3575812 You'll VS2012 or VS2013 to use `<chrono>`. If you can't, then use `boost` (see my note) : include `<boost/chrono.hpp>` and replace `std::` with `boost::`. Hope this helps.